# Check similarity between two string expressions in Swift

Tags: ios, regex, string, swift, text

I have scanned text:

```
Mils, chiiese, wh_ite ch$col_te
```

And expression list, example:

```
- cheese
- bread
- white chocolate
- etc.
```

I need compare broken expression with expression from my list, ex. "white chocolate" with "wh_ite ch$col_te."

Maybe you recommend some frameworks.

Answer (score 12):

## String distance - Levenshtein distance

What you need to do is measure the difference between two string. To do that, you can use the **[Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)**.

For your luck, somebody already implemented this algorihtm in Swift **[HERE](https://gist.github.com/bgreenlee/52d93a1d8fa1b8c1f38b)**.

To make it work in Swift 1.2, you'll just have to autofix some errors that occour, nothing too fancy.

**You can then use it like this:**

```
println(levenshtein("wh_ite ch$col_te", bStr: "white chocolate")) // prints 3, because you have to change 3 letters to get from aStr to bStr

println(levenshtein("wh_ite ch$col_te", bStr: "whsdfdsite chosdfsdfcolate")) // prints 13, because you have to change 13 letters to get from aStr to bStr
```

You then just set the tolerance and you are done!

Comment: how i can calculate ratio between strings ?

Answer (score 5):

Dejan Skledar's on the right track -- you want to make use of [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). The implementation he points to needs tweaking to work in Swift 1.2, and it tends to be slow. [**Here's a Swift 1.2-compatible, faster implementation.**](https://gist.github.com/kyro38/50102a47937e9896e4f4)

Simply include the `Tools` class in your project. Once you've done that, you can get a number representing the difference between two strings this way:

```
Tools.levenshtein("cheese", bStr: "chee_e") // returns 1
Tools.levenshtein("butter", bStr: "b_tt_r") // returns 2
Tools.levenshtein("milk", bStr: "butter")   // returns 6
```

Answer (score 3):

Please find the **Swift 4** implementation of Joey deVilla's answer [here](https://github.com/virumax/Levenshtein-swift4/blob/master/Tools.swift)

You have to call the function like below:

```
Tools.levenshtein(aStr: "Example", bStr: "Examples")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use StringMetric and be happy

https://github.com/autozimu/StringMetric.swift

```
import StringMetric

...

"kitten".distance(between: "sitting")    // => 0.746
"君子和而不同".distance(between: "小人同而不和")    // => 0.555
```