# How do I get the index of a multi-line string literal in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift4, multiline

I'm trying to find the index of a string that matches a specified value. One way to do this would be to use an instance method, but this assumes I'm working with an array; I'm working with a multi-line string literal. Much of the [documentation](https://www.agnosticdev.com/content/how-work-multi-line-string-literals-swift) on this topic concerns *making* multi-line string literals in Swift with *pre-defined* values.

Let's say I have the following multi-line string literal:

```
"""
Product 1 description
Product 1 color
Product 2 description
Product 2 color
"""
```

I'd like to define two variables: one to check if a global variable matches a string in the list above, and a second to act as the index. For example:

```
[In]  [1]: let keyword = "Product 2 description"
[In]  [2]: if keyword in multi-line string literal {
              print(index of match as integer)
           }
[Out] [3]: 2
```

I've managed to fulfil the first variable in my program by using the [Levenshtein distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365621/check-similarity-between-two-string-expressions-in-swift/30366763#30366763) calculator to find and define a match, but I'm having trouble fulfilling the second one. I've tried splitting the list and making tuples, but each string yielded an index of `0` when I `enumerated()` over the list. That said, if anyone could help me with *any* the following, I would much appreciate the help:

- Getting index values of the above multi-line string literal
- Defining a count variable whose value is an integer that changes over each string iteration
- Turning the above multi-line string literal into a list whereby each string has an index

Comment: Turn your *multiline literal* into an `[String]` with `let arr = mll.split(separator: "\n")`.

Comment: This will work for most strings, but not for those in my multiline literal — they contain special characters, so the code above turns each string into its own list item (i.e. `["Product 1 description"]\n["Product 1 color"]]\n["Product 2 description"]\n["Product 2 color"]`). Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: @solo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021712/how-to-split-a-string-by-new-lines-in-swift/32021850?s=1|44.6687#32021850

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried the three solutions that one user laid out in that thread — `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet`, `split`, and `enumerateLines`  — but my output hasn't changed; I keep getting each string as its own list item. Maybe this is because I'm getting my array from a `node` while parsing HTML, as I keep getting errors related to `node.text!` not being a `non-function type,` and I can't parse it for indexes.

Comment: componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet is the same as the accepted answer written with Swift 2 syntax

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` works for the question's [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'm now working on getting it to work for my program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create an array of the string by separating the lines

```
let string =
"""
Product 1 description
Product 1 color
Product 2 description
Product 2 color
"""

let list = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
```

Then you can get the index with

```
let indexOfProduct2Description = list.index(of: "Product 2 description")
```